# sIFR links not working on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, header, hyperlink, sifr

sIFR is used on a site developed by us for replacing some headers and links. The links are not working on Chrome, on everything else it's ok. With right-click on the sIFR link Chrome displays the right Flash-internal menu with 'Follow link' option and it leads to url we wanted. Just the normal single-click doesn't work.

Demo: http://teszt.ezpontaz.hu/

Any ideas are welcome, thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a site we just launched. The issue is, with Chrome, you can't have you text non-selectable. So looking at your site, you need to change your configuration to 'selectable: true'